# Dependency solver library for Perl

Tags: perl

I'm searching for a dependency solver library (think RPMS/dpkg but with my own database and portable to systems without rpms/dpkg) as a base for writing a custom package management system.

So far no luck on CPAN. One the one hand, the RPM-/Debian-related modules are tightly integrated with actual rpms/dpkg on the system (e.g. requiring librpm or dpkg/apt-get command-line program).

On the other hand there are things like [Algorithm-Dependency](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Dependency) or [Algorithm-DependencySolver](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-DependencySolver) but they only handle simple dependency, no handling of versions or complex dependencies as usually allowed by a software package system.

Any suggestions appreciated.

About the problem I'm trying to solve: modular deployment and update system of a largish software. Some components have been refactored into Perl distributions and we are using private CPAN system for installation/updates of these. Some other components are not Perl-based but they can be split into parts/packages. Generating OS packages (.deb, .rpm) have also been considered but we would like to target Windows too someday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [libzypp's sat solver](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE%3aLibzypp_satsolver). Both libzypp and libsatsolver come with Perl bindings.